# ffmpeg options for playing in iPad WebView with <video> tag

Tags: ios, video, webview, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video to be played in a  tag in a WebView in iOS. I've tried the options at [this link](https://develop.participatoryculture.org/index.php/ConversionMatrix) but it still doesn't seem to play. I've found videos that do successfully play, though, so I'm sure it's possible, I just can't seem to get any working. Here's the ffmpeg -i output for something that works.

Here's what I tried from the wiki:

```
ffmpeg -i {filename} -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1200k -f mp4 -threads 0 {filename}.ipad.mp4
```

But the file doesn't play in the WebView.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2005-12-20 20:20:15
  Duration: 00:01:25.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 209 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 115 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2005-12-20 20:20:15
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240, 90 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2005-12-20 20:20:15
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
```

And here's the output for my input file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cheerfulness.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-07-31 00:47:22
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 120849 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x1920, 120823 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-31 00:48:33
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

edit: Here's the full output of the command:

```
wlue:$ ffmpeg -i cheerfulness.mov -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1200k -f mp4 -threads 0 output.ipad.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 18 2013 18:44:15 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cheerfulness.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-07-31 00:47:22
  Duration: 00:00:06.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 120849 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x1920, 120823 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-31 00:48:33
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] frame MB size (75x120) > level limit (1620)
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] DPB size (5 frames, 17280000 bytes) > level limit (0 frames, 3110400 bytes)
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] MB rate (269730) > level limit (40500)
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] 264 - core 125 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1200 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=10000 vbv_bufsize=10000 nal_hrd=none ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.ipad.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1200x1920, q=-1--1, 1200 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-31 00:48:33
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  180 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=     828kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=1129.2kbits/s    
video:826kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.177851%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] frame I:2     Avg QP:32.23  size: 20942
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] frame P:178   Avg QP:41.03  size:  4515
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] mb I  I16..4: 90.1%  0.0%  9.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] mb P  I16..4:  6.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 16.8%  0.6%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:75.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] final ratefactor: 37.56
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 1.2% 16.4% 2.1% inter: 0.1% 3.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 49% 23%  4% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13%  8% 36%  8% 12%  9%  8%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 88%  6%  5%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] ref P L0: 47.7% 22.0% 16.7%  5.7%  7.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa67401fa00] kb/s:1126.21
```

Comment: I've added the ffmpeg command, and I actually already put the output of the console. :) Or was there something else I should add? I figured Stack Overflow was more appropriate since it's related to iOS and WebView programming, so it's more a programmer question rather than a general user problem.